# jetpack compose Image on entire screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple screen implemented with Jetpack Compose,
here is a preview of the screen.

[image]

There is a button like the sun on the TopAppBar which the user clicks to take a screenshot.

The problem is that I want to show the screenshot of the entire screen but without showing the status bar and the navigation bar.

Is there a solution to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The composables are tied to a `View` which you can access with `LocalView.current` and through that `View` you can retrieve its `.context` and through that you can get to its `Activity` and to the `Window` object.

Once you have a reference to the `Window` (and to the `View`, if you have to support API level lower than 30), you can control status bar and navigation bar visibility.

A code example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyFullScreenComposable() {
    val view = LocalView.current
    SideEffect {
        requestFullScreen(view)
    }

    Box {
        // ... other content
   
        Button(
            onClick = { requestFullScreen(view) }
        ) {
            Text("Go fullscreen")
        }
    }
}
    
fun requestFullScreen(view: View) {
    // !! should be safe here since the view is part of an Activity
    val window = view.context.getActivity()!!.window
    WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).hide(
        WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars() or
                WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars()
    )
}

fun Context.getActivity(): Activity? = when (this) {
    is Activity -> this
    // this recursion should be okay since we call getActivity on a view context
    // that should have an Activity as its baseContext at some point
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.getActivity()
    else -> null
}
```

In your case you might have to hide your action/title bar as well (or maybe you are already doing that).

Note that when the user taps on the screen while in full-screen mode, the bars will slide back. That's why I added a button as an example how you can let the user go back into full-screen mode through an action. In your case that could be a FloatingActionButton or some action on a semi-transparent top action bar.